# Remote EJB Injection via @Produces - ClassCastException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

i am going to continue to express my seemingly endless missunderstanding in EJBs:

I am using JBoss 8 (Wildfly 8.1) as my Applicationserver.

I am currently building a workaround for the Problem, that Inpustreams cannot be passed to remote EJB via RMI (which makes absolute sense once i thought about it).

I i must not replace the existing Resources Interface (writing an Inpustream to a File) I build following 3 Projects as a solution:

**Interfaces (library included in both EARs):**

```
com.package.ejb
public interface StorageAdapter extends Serializable{
    String store(Inpustream is); (//returns an id
    Inputstream load(String id);
}

public interface StorageAdapterProvider{
    StorageAdapter provide();
}
```

**Persistence-EAR**

```
com.package.impl
public class FileSystemStorageAdapter implements com.package.ejb.Storageadapter {
//implementation, writing to locally mounted path in filesystem...
}

com.package.impl
@Singleton
@Remote(com.package.ejb.StorageAdapterProvider.class)
public class StorageAdapterProviderBean implements  com.package.ejb.StorageadapterProvider {

    public StorageAdapter provide() {
        return new FileSystemStorageAdapter(); 
    }
}
```

**Business-EAR**

```
com.package.business

public class StorageProvider {
    @EJB(looklup = "java:global/Persistence-EAR/StorageAdapterProviderBean!com.package.ejb.StorageAdapterProvider"
    private StorageAdapterProvider provider;

    @Produces
    public StorageAdapter getStorageAdapter() {
    return provider.provide();
    }

}
```

I then use `@Inject StorageAdapter storageAdapter;` to get an instance of the Storageadapter-implementation.

Business-EAR/Storageprovider then throws a `ClassCastException`, telling me that `com.package.impl.FileSystemStorageAdapter cannot be cast to com.package.ejb.StorageAdapter`

i added some logging to the EJB

```
com.package.impl
@Singleton
@Remote(com.package.ejb.StorageAdapterProvider.class)
public class StorageAdapterProviderBean implements  com.package.ejb.StorageadapterProvider {

    public StorageAdapter provide() {
    StroageAdapter ret = new FileSystemStorageAdapter();
          logger.info("EJB: RETURNING Stortage adapter");
    logger.info("    is of type:"+ret.getClass().getName());
    logger.info("        is Storageadapter: "+ (ret instanceof StorageAdapter));
    logger.info("        is FileSystemStorageAdapter: "+ (ret instanceof FileSystemStorageAdapter));
    return ret;
    }
}
```

and it correctly prints:

```
EJB: RETURNING Stortage adapter
is of type:com.package.impl.FileSystemStorageAdapter
is Storageadapter: true
is FileSystemStorageAdapter: true
```

Further investigation shows, that the Exception is thrown while the container is Wrapping the "ret" Object, as i also get the Exeption if i chnage the @Provides implementation to:

```
    Object o = provider.provide();
```

Is it impossible to return an Interface type from an EJB?
What am i missing?
Does Business-EJB need to know the implementing Classes? - Wouldn't a ClassNotFound Exception make more sense in this case?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

My Packaging looks as follows:

Persistence.ear

```
 -lib/Interfaces.jar
  -StorageAdapter
  -Storageprovider
 -persistence_ejb.jar
  -FileSystemStorageAdapter
  -StorageAdapterProviderBean
```

Business.ear

```
 -lib/Interfaces.jar
  -StorageAdapter
  -Storageprovider
 -business_ejb.jar
  -StorageProvider 
 -web.war
  -Jaxrsres
```

The `Jaxrsres` is the one having a Storageadapter Injected via `@Inject`
I am deploying these 2 wars to a JBoss Wildlfly 8.1 Server.

I did not make any relevant changes to the configuration - so all the other Point you requested are defaults as far as I understand.

EDIT2:
It somewhat defeats the purpose, but it works if i add the `Persistence.ear/persistence_ejb.jar` to the libraries of `Business.ear`.

Business.ear

```
 -lib
  -Interfaces.jar
   -StorageAdapter
   -Storageprovider
  -persistence_ejb.jar
   -FileSystemStorageAdapter
   -StorageAdapterProviderBean
 -business_ejb.jar
  -StorageProvider 
 -web.war
  -Jaxrsres
```

This is obviously not what I want though :/

The main Point is, i want to be able to redeploy Persistence.ear with, say, "DatabaseStorageAdapter", without touching business.ear.

The "Dream" is to Provide the Storageadapter as an EJB Directly - but as the Interface is fixed and needs an InputStream, this cannot be done.

Comment: I need to know more details about how you're packaged and which container / classloading scheme you're using.  Suffice to say you can get a ClassCastException if you're casting a class to itself, but it was loaded by two different classloaders.  Check to see if you have the interface class included more than once and consider moving it to the lib folder of the EAR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you suggest that the Container does not recognize the Class as implementation of this Interface, because the Interface for one ear is loaded by a different Classloader?

Comment: Yes, I would expect that this is a classloader issue.  The two ears, however, have isolated classloaders.  Your problem is somewhere in the client ear.

Comment: well, as stated i figured out, i can provide the EJB implementation as lib to the client ear to get it working - but i want to be able to exchange the Persistence.ear without touching the business.ear's deployment. Do you have any other idea to achieve this?

Comment: You don't need to provide the implementation class.  I'm trying to tell you that I believe the interface class is loaded twice within the same ear.  I don't have enough information here to tell you why.

Comment: In JBoss, you should be able to do a getClass().getClassLoader().  The toString() method identifies which module or sub-module loaded the class, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @jgitter - i checked, it is not loaded twice - plus making the Implementation known fixes the Error

Comment: I don't have enough information here.  Can you add the stack trace and the remote interface?

Comment: remote interface is the second entry int he first codeblock. I ll try to find a trace - I have since then moved on to other approaches